# Filename unable to load while creating Lambda function in AWS using Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I am trying to create a basic Lambda function in AWS using Terraform. In my .tf file I am defining the required parameters for Lambda creation. While executing `terraform apply` command, I am receiving following error:

```
aws_lambda_function.test_lambda: Unable to load "main.zip": open main.zip: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have placed a zip with a `JS` file in it in the same path as the `.tf` file. As per Terraform documents "filename" parameter is not mandatory. I am unable to execute if I ignore this parameter. Could someone help me?

Comment: @KMK please, share your terraform code

Comment: are you using "${path.module}/main.zip" or "${path.cwd}/main.zip" or "${path.root}/main.zip" to indicate the location of the file? https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/interpolation.html#path-information

Comment: @c4f4t0r Please find the code attached

   resource "aws_lambda_function" "test_lambda" {
  function_name    = "firstLambdaFunction"
  filename         = "main.zip"
  role             = "arn:aws:iam:role/service-role/lambdaRole"
  handler          = "exports.test"
  runtime          = "nodejs8.10"
}

Comment: @victorm since the zip file is in the same path as .tf file, I am simply assigning  filename argument value as "main.zip". Even I tried giving exact path "${path.cwd}\\main.zip. The error message is the same "The system cannot find the file specified"

Comment: Are you running this on windows? Terraform translates the "//" properly across OS. So either use "./main.zip" or "${path.cwd}/main.zip" or try "${path.root}/main.zip" which is the same